Signed Magnitude Operation
"Calculate the following operation using signed magnitude representation:
(-53) - 79 = ?"
I know the answer is overflow, but I can’t seem to prove it through my calculations. Here are my results so far:
-53(10) = 10110101(2)(signed magnitude)
-79(10) = 11001111(2)(signed magnitude)
carry:   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
-53:       1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
-79:      +1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
result:    1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
Could someone help me? From my understanding of the carry rules in binary arithmetic, that extra 1 should be discarded since it’s followed by another 1. Am I mistaken? I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Note: It has to be on the 8 bit format.

It gives overflow only if you insist on $8$ bit representation. Generally   with $-53-79=-132 = (1\ 1000\ 0100)_2$ is no problem, if/when you have extra bit for sign. But if you are restricted for $8$ bit, then of course $(1000\ 0100)_2 = -4$ is result of overflow.

Oh, my apologies, I didn't clarify that it had to be on 8 bit. I figured it was doable after proof checking the result.
I still want to understand how i could prove it is overflow considering the Carry rule I mentioned, this one specific problem has  kept me stuck for a while. Would it be just through reversing binary to decimal or there is another way?

When we insist on $8$ bit representation representation, then leftmost bit is reserved for sign and only $7$ bits we have for magnitude. Maximum value for it is $2^7-1=127$, so it is impossible to place $132 = (1000\ 0100)_2$ in $7$ bits.

So, like i said, the only way to prove it is overflow is through reversing binary to decimal at the end? I already knew from the start it was overflow, but it has through be proved through calculations.

Through calculations you obtain $-132$ which cannot be represented  in $8$ bit sign-magnitude, because all numbers there are between $\pm 127$. Is such proof acceptable?

Let's assume you do not want decimal operations: then we obtain $-53-79=-4$ using only binary operations and this also shows overflow. When we are adding numbers with same sign, then magnitude should increase but here we have reverse case.

Oh, I see it now. Thank you! I was using the decimal method to prove it previously, it's nice to see another way.
